How can I get the Interact.jl and WebIO.jl package to install and work properly in Julia?
I'm trying to write an interactive program using the Interact.jl packege with JupyterLab.
Firstly I have installted IJulia.jl, Conda.jl, WebIO.jl and Interact.jl packages in the package manager.
To install the WebIO Jupyter extantion, following code was executed. This process was probably properly finished.
using Conda
Conda.pip_interop(true)
Conda.pip("install", "webio_jupyter_extension")
However, subsequent code to install the required JupyterLab extension:
using WebIO
WebIO.install_jupyter_labextension()

showed the error message as follows:
The WebIO Jupyter extension must be installed using Python or Conda. See 
https://juliagizmos.github.io/WebIO.jl/latest/providers/ijulia/ for more information.

I think the WebIO Jupyter extantion has been installed by Conda.pip("install", "webio_jupyter_extension").
Is there something wrong? Could you please share with me your wisdom?
